# How do I test a method that requires a file's presence?

Tags: python, unit-testing

For the first time, I'm using Python to create a library, and I'm trying to take the opportunity in this project to learn unit testing. I've written a first method and I want to write some unit tests for it. (Yes, I know that TDD requires I write the test first, I'll get there, really.)

The method is fairly simple, but it expects that the class has a `file` attribute set, that the attribute points to an existing file, and that the file is an archive of some sort (currently only working with zip files, tar, rar, etc., to be added later). The method is supposed to return the number of files in the archive.

I've created a folder in my project called `files` that contains a few sample files, and I've manually tested the method and it works as it should so far. The manual test looks like this, located in the `archive_file.py` file:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    archive = ArchiveFile()

    script_path = path.realpath(__file__)
    parent_dir = path.abspath(path.join(script_path, os.pardir))
    targ_dir = path.join(parent_dir, 'files')
    targ_file = path.join(targ_dir, 'test.zip' )

    archive.file = targ_file

    print(archive.file_count())
```

All I do then is make sure that what's printed is what I expect given the contents of `test.zip`.

Here's what `file_count` looks like:

```
def file_count(self):
    """Return the number of files in the archive."""
    if self.file == None:
        return -1

    with ZipFile(self.file) as zip:
        members = zip.namelist()
        # Remove folder members if there are any.
        pruned = [item for item in members if not item.endswith('/')]
        return len(pruned)
```

Directly translating this to a unit test seems wrong to me for a few reasons, some of which may be invalid. I'm counting on the precise location of the test files in relation to the current script file, I'll need a large sample of manually created archive files to make sure I'm testing enough variations, and, of course, I'm manually comparing the returned value to what I expect because I know how many files are in the test archive.

It *seems* to me that this should be automated as much as possible, but it also seems that doing so is going to be very complicated.

What's the proper way to create unit tests for such a class method?

Comment: Have you considered [mocking](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwivsdK7nYfOAhVD7mMKHSWxDXkQFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpypi.python.org%2Fpypi%2Fmock&usg=AFQjCNGurnzZ47GvhKvsnHFDpGYrmDVLNg) the object?

Comment: @Oasiscircle, that's the "I'm trying to take the opportunity to learn unit testing" idea. I don't understand mocking, or fixtures. Python tutorials on unit testing seem to assume that I understand these concepts, while unit testing tutorials tend to concentrate on a specific language, such as Java, which I'm not very conversant in. I guess I'm hoping someone can give me an example using Python's unittest module and whatever other built-in Python features I would need for mocking and fixtures.

Comment: I provided a link in my comment, I just figured I'd give you the language (I didn't know the mock module existed until a few years ago) to find potentially good resources. Maybe google "python mock examples".

Comment: @Oasiscircle I'll do that, but I'm at the point in ignorance of not knowing that what I'm looking for is mocking (well, until you suggested it :) ). If I understand mocking and its implementation in Python, does that solve my problem? I don't yet know what I don't know.

Comment: I believe that examining mock would greatly help you with this type of issue. Unit tests are so low level that it's beneficial to get abstract away any function that uses something on the OS (like the file system) and the mock module provides the functionality and framework for creating "fake" constructs (modules, objects, instances) that return pre-determined values allowing you to better test the interface of your design and how your interfaces work together. The proper time to actually test the internal workings of your functions is during CI tests. (Think Travis if you're on Github)

Comment: For instance, you can mock the `os` module's `listdir()` function to return a pre-determined amount for the single unit test without actually having to construct a directory with those files. Etc etc.

Comment: @Oasiscircle I'm reading some articles on Python mocking now, but it sounds like that might not test what I want it to. In testing this particular method, I want to ensure that given an archive, it returns the right number of contained files. Another test I'd want would be, given a non-existent file or a non-archive file, it returns an error. It sounds like mocking would by pass both of those because the objects are virtual? I might be misunderstanding this, of course, and perhaps reading these articles will help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118036/discussion-between-oasiscircle-and-chuck).

Comment: Negative one (-1) isn't a file count. If `self.file` requires a non-`None` value, raise an exception when that is not true instead of returning a sentinel value that looks like a valid return value.

Comment: @chepner, I know, eventually I'll be raising errors. This is just the first draft of the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Oasiscircle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5763213/oasiscircle) and [dm03514](https://stackoverflow.com/users/594589/dm03514) were very helpful on this and lead me to the right answer eventually, especially with dm's answer to a [followup question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38556197/how-do-i-mock-a-classs-functions-return-value).

What needs to be done is to use the `mock` library to create a fake version of `ZipFile` that won't object to there not actually being a file, but will instead return valid lists when using the `nameslist` method.

```
@unittest.mock.patch('comicfile.ZipFile')
def test_page_count(self, mock_zip_file):
    comic_file = ComicFile()
    members = ['dir/', 'dir/file1', 'dir/file2']
    mock_zip_file.return_value.__enter__.return_value.namelist.return_value \
                = members
    self.assertEqual(2, self.comic_file.page_count())
```

The `__enter__.return_value` portion above is necessary because in the code being tested the `ZipFile` instance is being created within a context manager.

Comment: What is a `ComicFile`?

Comment: @buhtz, well, since this was six years ago, I don't even remember the project I was working on. Can't find the project on my laptop or GitHub, but it's probably a wrapper class for the various formats comic book files are commonly published in. `cb*` files are comic book archives, where the last characters indicates the compression format, RAR, ZIP, TAR, etc. https://www.lifewire.com/cdisplay-archived-comic-book-files-2620157

Answer (score 2):

There are so many different way to approach this.  I like to think what would be valuable to test, off the top of my head, I can think of a couple things:

- validation logic (`if self.file == None`)
- pruning logic
- that all file types claimed to be supported are actually supported

This testing could take place on two levels:

1. Unittest your logic
2. Test integration (ie supported archive types against the filesystem)

**Unittest the logic**

Unittesting the logic of your archive objects should be trivial.  There looks to be a couple tests in your file_count method that could be valuable:

- `test_no_file_returns_negative_one` (error conditions are "hopefully" not very frequently executed code paths, and are great candidates for tests. Especially if your clients are expecting this `-1` return value.
- `test_zip_file_pruned_logic` this looks to be very important functionality in your code, if implemented incorrectly it would completely throw off the count that your code is claiming to be able to return
- `test_happy_path_file_count_successful` I like to have a unittest that exercises the whole function, using mocked dependencies `ZipFile` to make sure that everything is covered, without having to run the integration tests.

**Test Integrations**

I think a test for each supported archive type would be very valuable.  These could be static fixtures that live in your repo, and your tests would already know how many files that each archive has and would assert on that.

I think all of your concerns are valid, and all of them can be addressed, and tested, in a maintainable way:

**I'm counting on the precise location of the test files in relation to the current script file**

This could be addressed by the convention of having your file fixtures stored in a subdirectory of your test package, and then using python to get the file path of your test package:

`FIXTURE_DIR = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'fixtures')`

For portable code it will be important to dynamically generate these paths.

**I'll need a large sample of manually created archive files to make sure I'm testing enough variations**

Yes, how many are good enough? AT LEAST a test per supported archive type. (netflix has to test against every single device that they have an app on :), plenty of companies have to run tests against large matrix of mobile devices)  I think the test coverage here is crucial, but try to put all the edge cases that need to be covered in unittests.

**I'm manually comparing the returned value to what I expect because I know how many files are in the test archive.**

The archive will have to become static and your test will store that information.

---

One thing to keep in mind are the scopes of your tests.  Making a test that exercise `ZipFile` wouldn't be very valuable because its in the stdlibrary and already has tests.  Additionally, testing that your code works with all python filesystems/os' probably wouldn't be very valuable either, as python already has those checks.

But scoping your tests to verify that your application works with all file types that it says it supports, I believe, is extremely valuable, because it is a contract between you and your clients, saying "hey this DOES work, let me show you".  The same way that python's tests are a contract between it and you saying "Hey we support OSX/LINUX/whatever let me show you"

Answer (score 0):

Suggest refactoring the pruning logic to a separate method that does not depend on file or ZipFile. This:

```
def file_count(self):
    ...
    with ZipFile(self.file) as zip:
        members = zip.namelist()
        # Remove folder members if there are any.
        pruned = [item for item in members if not item.endswith('/')]
        return len(pruned)
```

Becomes:

```
def file_count(self):
    ...
    with ZipFile(self.file) as zip:
        return len(self.prune_dirs(zip.namelist()))

def prune_dirs(self, members):
    # Remove folder members if there are any.
    pruned = [item for item in members if not item.endswith('/')]
    return pruned
```

Now, testing prune_dirs can be done without any test files.

```
members = ["a/", "a/b/", "a/b/c", "a/b/d"]
print archive.prune_dirs(members)
```

If you want to avoid integration testing, then you have to fake or mock ZipFile. In this case, any object that provides the method namelist() would do.

```
class FakeZipFile():

    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename

    def namelist(self):
        return ['a', 'b/', 'c']
```

Now I introduce a new method get_helper() on ArchiveFile

```
class ArchiveFile():

    def get_helper(self):
        return ZipFile(self.filename)

    def file_count(self):
        ...
        helper = self.get_helper()
        return len(self.prune_dirs(helper.namelist()))
```

...and override get_helper() in a Testing child class.

```
class ArchiveFileTesting(ArchiveFile):

    def get_helper(self):
        return FakeZipFile(self.file);
```

A testing class let's you override just what you need from ArchiveFile to eliminate the dependency on ZipFile. In your test, use the testing class and I think you have good coverage.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    archive = ArchiveFileTesting()
```

You will probably want to think of ways to change namelist so you can test more cases than the one shown here.

Comment: I think it's generally an anti pattern for test specific code , the same thing could be accomplished with a test specific subclass that overrides get helper method to return stubbed object, or many other ways to configure archive to return fake zip file without test specific logic. It sets precedent for env specific logic which quickly becomes unmaintainable, in my experiences

Comment: I like the test-specific subclass to avoid the testing variable. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Mocking works.
Another approach is setting up an environment.

For your use case, setting up an environment would mean creating a temporary directory, copy whatever kinds of files you expect to live there, and run your tests in it.

You do have to add a parameter or a global that tells your code in what directory to look.

This has been working quite well for me. However, my use case is somewhat different in that I am writing tests for code that uses an external program, so I have no way to mock anything.