# How do I mock a class's function's return value?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a method in Python that looks like this (in `comicfile.py`):

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

...

class ComicFile():
    ...

    def page_count(self):
        """Return the number of pages in the file."""
        if self.file == None:
            raise ComicFile.FileNoneError()

        if not os.path.isfile(self.file):
            raise ComicFile.FileNotFoundError()

        with ZipFile(self.file) as zip:
            members = zip.namelist()
            pruned = self.prune_dirs(members)
            length = len(pruned)
            return length
```

I'm trying to write a unit test for this (I've already tested `prune_dirs`), and so for this is what I have (`test_comicfile.py`):

```
import unittest
import unittest.mock

import comicfile

...

class TestPageCount(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.comic_file = comicfile.ComicFile()

    @unittest.mock.patch('comicfile.ZipFile')
    def test_page_count(self, mock_zip_file):
        # Store as tuples to use as dictionary keys.
        members_dict = {('dir/', 'dir/file1', 'dir/file2'):2,
                        ('file1.jpg', 'file2.jpg', 'file3.jpg'):3
        }

        # Make the file point to something to prevent FileNoneError.
        self.comic_file.file = __file__

        for file_tuple, count in members_dict.items():
            mock_zip_file.return_value.namelist = list(file_tuple)
            self.assertEqual(count, self.comic_file.page_count())
```

When I run this test, I get the following:

```
F..ss....
======================================================================
FAIL: test_page_count (test_comicfile.TestPageCount)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/unittest/mock.py", line 1157, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "/Users/chuck/Dropbox/Projects/chiv/chiv.cbstar/test_comicfile.py", line 86, in test_page_count
    self.assertEqual(count, self.comic_file.page_count())
AssertionError: 2 != 0

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 9 tests in 0.010s

FAILED (failures=1, skipped=2)
```

OK, so `self.comic_file.page_count()` is returning `0`. I tried placing the following line after `members = zip.namelist()` in `page_count`.

```
print('\nmembers -> ' + str(members))
```

During the test, I get this:

```
members -> <MagicMock name='ZipFile().__enter__().namelist()' id='4483358280'>
```

I'm quite new to unit testing and am quite nebulous on using `unittest.mock`, but my understanding is that `mock_zip-file.return_value.namelist = list(file_tuple)` should have made it so that the `namelist` method of the `ZipFile` class would return each of the `file_tuple` contents in turn. What it *is* doing I have no idea.

I think what I'm trying to do here is clear, but I can't seem to figure out how to override the `namelist` method so that my unit test is only testing this one function instead of having to deal with `ZipFile` as well.

Comment: Your code is confusing.  Are 'ComicFile' and 'comicfile' 1 class (once misspelled) or 2?  Should 'Zipfile' in the first snippet by 'self.Zipfile'?  Without knowing the details, I wonder if you even need the mock.  Each test should assume that everything else works.  You only question that when a test fails.  There needs to be a positive reason to mock something.  For instance, 'the call will fail in the test setting' or 'calling a real object takes too much time or space' or 'the return is not deterministic'.

Comment: It's quite possible that I'm using non-Pythonic naming conventions, although I'm trying to conform to them. `ComicFile` is the class, `comicfile` is the module containing the class. `ZipFile` is imported via `from zipfile import ZipeFile`. I *think* I need to mock because if I don't, in order to test this I'd actually need to have zip files in the file system, and I just want to test that, if a zip file object returns a `namelist`, this function correctly counts the number of files.

Comment: mock IS confusing, especially regarding context managers.

Comment: Mocking an external resource *is* a good use.  If I were *not* using it as a context manager and were only making the one function call, I might temporarily replace Zipfile with "class Zipfile:\n  def namelist(): return ...".  But for this case, I also learned something from dm03514's great answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ZipFile` is instantiated as a [context manager](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2016/03/07/python-with-context-managers/).  to [mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#calling) it you have to refer to its `__enter__` method.

`mock_zip_file.return_value.__enter__.return_value.namelist.return_value = list(file_tuple)`

What you're trying to do is very clear, but the context manager adds complexity to the mocking.

---

One trick is that when a mock registers all calls made to it, in this example it is saying it has a call at:

`members -> <MagicMock name='ZipFile().__enter__().namelist()' id='4483358280'>`

This can guide you in registering your mocked object, replace all `()` with `return_value`

Comment: OK, first, tyvm. I copied and pasted and got the test to work and the prints I'd placed throughout the code show what I expect them to (the mocked members). Of course, I don't yet understand *why* it works, that's going to bug me until I figure it out. I've read the `mock` docs a few times, but I'll take a look at the article you linked to and perhaps that'll help me understand what that kind of code means.

Comment: I (think) I understand now. If I'd set `zip` without the `with` block, but with just `zip = ZipFile...`, then `mock_zip_file.return_value.namelist.return_value = list(file_tuple)` would have worked. The `__enter__` in the `print` you quoted should have alerted me that the path I was using to get to `namevalue` was incorrect.